# Multipart queries in SQL Server with RODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc

I am trying to use `GO` to get R to pull a multipart query from a SQL Server database but R keeps erroring out on me when I try this. Does anyone know a workaround to get RODBC to run multipart queries?

Example query:

```
query2 = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ATTTempTable') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #ATTTempTable

GO

SELECT
    * INTO #ATTTempTable
FROM ETL.ATT.fact_responses fr
WHERE fr.ResponseDateTime > '2015-07-06'
"
channel <- odbcConnect("<host name>", uid="<uid>", pwd="<pwd>")
raw = sqlQuery(channel, query2)
close(channel)
```

and result

```
> raw
[1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."                                                                                                                                               
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ATTTempTable') IS NOT NULL\n  DROP TABLE #ATTTempTable\n\nGO\n\nSELECT\n\t* INTO #ATTTempTable\nFROM ETL.ATT.fact_responses fr\nWHERE fr.ResponseDateTime > '2015-07-06'\n'"
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your query contains multiple line with conditional logic it resembles a stored procedure.

Simply save that stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sqlServerSp @ResponseDateTime nvarchar(10)
AS    
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ATTTempTable') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #ATTTempTable;    
GO    
-- suppresses affected rows message so RODBC returns a dataset 
SET NO COUNT ON;  
GO
-- runs make-table action query
SELECT * INTO #ATTTempTable
FROM ETL.ATT.fact_responses fr
WHERE fr.ResponseDateTime > @ResponseDateTime;
GO
```

And then run the stored procedure in R. You can even pass parameters like the date:

```
channel <- odbcConnect("<host name>", uid="<uid>", pwd="<pwd>")
raw = sqlQuery(channel, "EXEC sqlServerSp @ResponseDateTime='2015-07-06'")
close(channel)
```

Comment: I have a stored procedure that works just fine on the server but when I try to execute it in the Rstudio environment it just returns an `integer(0)` response, not even an error message. I have also gotten error messages like `[1] "42000 2812 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'getAttCeData'."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'EXEC getAttCeData'"` but that was just because I was connecting to the wrong database within the server. Do you know why it might not be returning any result data set? The procedure works fine when in MSSQL

Comment: Try adding the `dbo` prefix: `exec dbo.getAttCeData`. Inside MSSQL you do not have to explicitly add `dbo` but outside it may be required.

Comment: Actually, what worked was `set nocount on` so that RODBC wouldn't think I was done before the full procedure actually executed. That's why I was getting `integer(0)` responses

Answer (score 0):

You can't. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

you have to divide your query into two statements and run them separately.